# Where do I go after finding the broken communications wire?

Tags: firewatch

I've found the broken communications wire but I can't seem to figure out where to go next. I can't climb back on the rock that I jumped down from and there is a "blocked trail" but I don't see where I can continue. This is my location on the map:

[image: Location on map]

Where do I go to continue my journey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a lot more simpler than I thought. Looking downhill from the broken communications wire, all you have to do is continue toward the right side of the hill and you may move on.

[image: screenshot of hill]